# javascript inheritance, constructor called twice

Tags: javascript, inheritance

```
function Parent (arg1, arg2) {

    alert(arg1);

    this.member1 = arg1;
    this.member2 = arg2;
};

Parent.prototype.update = function () {

    // parent method update
};

function Child (arg1, arg2, arg3) {

    Parent.call(this, arg1, arg2);
    this.member3 = arg3;
};

Child.prototype = new Parent;

Child.prototype.update = function () {

    // overwritten method update
};

function init () {

    var childObject = new Child(false, false, false);
    childObject.update();
}
```

The result are two alerts with

1. undefined
2. false

Why does the alert occurs two times? I already searched, but haven't found anything yet + don't know what to search for.

The result should be one alert with 'false', or am i wrong?

Thx alot!

Comment: the first alert is called here: `Child.prototype = new Parent;`

Comment: oh man. thx! so just remove the new...

Comment: No, you can't just remove `new` keyword. See `steveukx` answer for correct approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the constructor of `Parent` to create the prototype for `Child`, the constructor is being called which is your first alert of `undefined`.

In order to create a prototype that still uses the same prototype chain, but doesn't call the parent constructor as the prototype is created, you need to add another step in between.

```
Child.prototype = (function() {
  var Base = function() {};
  Base.prototype = Parent.prototype;
  return new Base();
}());
```

This will create an anonymous function (called `Base`) that has the prototype set to be the prototype of the `Parent` class, the `Child` prototype is then assigned to a new `Base` which will preserve the inheritance, but doesn't call the constructor of `Parent` as the prototype chain is created.

Answer (score 0):

There is one alert when you create a new object of Parent `Child.prototype = new Parent;` and one when you create new object of child, `var childObject = new Child(false, false, false);`